# $f[0, 0, 0]$, divided difference on one point

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

There is this question I saw somewhere, saying:

Assume $f = \sin(2x) $, what's the value of divided differences $ f[0, 0, 0] $ and
$ f[\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}] $?

So, I know the final answer is $ 0 $ and $\frac{4}{3}$, but I can't understand why. Because it seems to me that by applying the definition of divided difference, there's gonna be some $0$'s in the denominator (because well, all the $x$'s in the definition are the same) and thus the divided difference should be undefined.

Comment: Divided differences with repeated interpolation points are computed using the *derivatives* of the function at those points. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2683112/42969.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot mate.